# Dynamic form with different form fields with logic where next set of form fields changes based off answer to current set of form field answers

Tags: c#, sql, parent-child, nlp-question-answering

First:  I couldnt use the word:  question in my title, so I used form field instead.

Bear with me on my question/explanation what I already have vs. what I need:

What I need:  The ability to dynamically pull a first set of questions from a database and have then answered and then based off the answers to the first set of questions display a second set of questions that changes based off answers to first set of questions (and based off those answers to the second set of questions a different 3rd set will be displayed) and so on (the number of levels is not set and is dynamic/can change).

What I have already:  A C# ASP.NET web application with classes and a SQL DB back end.  The programming on a form that takes a set of questions that are grouped together and based of what grouping is passed to the form it pulls dynamic questions (and possible answers) from a database (there can be many different question/answer groupins and the form chagnes the questions based off that grouping) and displays the questions on the screen.  It also pulls the type of form field required for the questions (textbox, select, checkbox, radio, etc) and dynamically buiulds out the form fields and if needed the options for the select/checkbox/radio and also adds validation to the form.  Then when then user submits the form, it saves the answers to the DB and can retrive the anssers dynamically as well.

I also have the ability/logic to have the questions have a parent/child relationship (dynamic with no set level of parent/child relationships).

What I need is:  To have the ability to use my logic/db structure above but to display a set of questions questions then based off answers to the first set of questions, change the second set of questions that are displayed.

I can easily hard code the logic using if/else and case statements but I need this to be dynamic and I want to seperate out the logic/code from the questions/answers so I can easily add/remove/update the question trees without updating any code just data.

Ex:  So questions 1, 2, 3 are displayed on the first form.  The user answers 1:A, 2:A, 3:B.  Based off those answers questions 4, 5, 9 are displayed.  If they answerd 1:B, 2:A, 3:C, then questions 4, 7, 9 are displayed.  Also some questions answers may not have an impact on the next set of answers that are displaeyd.  Additionally I may have 1 question stored in the database that can appear at level 1 of a set of questions, but nested at level 4 of a second set of questions.  All this needs to be dynamically pulled from the database.

I already have most of the code/logic/functionality I need, I just need to expand on what I already have to allow for this additinal/new set of functionality I want to have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be an overly simplistic idea to a very complex question...

Create another table akin to this

```
SetLogic         | NextQuestionSet
'1:A, 2:A, 3:B'  | '4,5,9'
'1:B, 2:A, 3:C'  | '4,7,9'
```

OR

```
SetLogic         | QuestionId
'1:A, 2:A, 3:B'  | 4
'1:A, 2:A, 3:B'  | 5
'1:A, 2:A, 3:B'  | 9
'1:B, 2:A, 3:C'  | 4
'1:B, 2:A, 3:C'  | 7
'1:B, 2:A, 3:C'  | 9
```

Create a stored proc that sends up the @SetLogicIn, select from the new table what questions you want to ask next.

Here is a function for splitting table up NextQuestionSet, if you decide to go that direction

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitForDelimiter]
(    
      @delimiter VARCHAR(10),
      @input VARCHAR(1000)

)
RETURNS @tempTable TABLE(
data VARCHAR(100)
)
BEGIN

DECLARE @tempstr VARCHAR(1000)
SET @tempstr = @input
WHILE(charindex(@delimiter,@tempstr,0) > 0)
BEGIN
      DECLARE @t VARCHAR(100)
      SET @t = Substring(@tempstr,0,(charindex(@delimiter,@tempstr,0)))
      INSERT into @tempTable (data) VALUES (@t)
      SET @tempstr = Substring(@tempstr,charindex(@delimiter,@tempstr,0)+1,Len(@tempstr))
      if(charindex(@delimiter,@tempstr,0) <=0)
      BEGIN
      INSERT into @tempTable (data) VALUES (@tempstr)
      END
END
```

Comment: I went through a few iterations of what/how to do this and finally came up with solution (it is more advanced/complicated and adds another level of dynamic ability to what you posted) but I was able to use what you posted as a starting point so I wanted to award you the points.  Since it is complicated (and tied so much into my other code) I cant really post what my final solution was.  I would have to write more of an article then post it here. :)  Thanks for the assist!

Comment: @Brad - You're quite welcome!  Keep up the good work.